# How to create a trigger that triggers logstash to run on certain log files daily?

Tags: java, rest, triggers, jersey, logstash

How can I create a trigger that makes logstash run on log files and do some analysis at a certain point of time daily?

Comment: do you have access to the server and can modify the crontab?

Comment: What have you done so far? What about cron jobs, schedulers or using a framework like camel, which has everything you need?

Comment: I have copied the logs into my local hard drive and I have analyzed those logs using logstash along with GROK filters. And then I implemented a java REST service which I'm using to analyze the output data from logstash to identify some dependencies between the analyzed data of logstash.

Comment: Great. I'll try to use cron. I think it will be suitable.

Comment: Yes. I have access to the servers where the log files are stored.